# SQL: Field values appear in SELECT * but cannot query with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using CloudSQL on GCP and have a simple table. When I run

```
SELECT Staff, JobCode FROM tblData
```

I get my results:

```
+--------------+---------+
| Staff        | JobCode |
+--------------+---------+
    JON SMITHE | C232
    JON SMITHE | C097
    JON SMITHE | C232
    JON SMITHE | C097
    JON SMITHE | C232
    JON SMITHE | C097
```

When I want to specify the JobCode specifically:

```
SELECT Staff, JobCode FROM tblData WHERE JobCode = 'C097'
```

I get an empty set. All the other fields in the table can be queried with the WHERE clause except this 'JobCode' field. The data type is VARCHAR(45).

I've tried the following:

- Delete the data and reimport
- Delete the table and recreate, then reimport

Comment: You probably have spaces or other invisible characters in that field. Use the hex() function to find it out what is there.

Comment: Try LIKE '%C097%' to see if that matches anything

Comment: Tip: don't store 'C'. Whatever the public (humanly readable) job code is, this doesn't need to be the same as the database internal id (and in my view, it shouldn't)

Comment: This did the trick!! There is something off with the string 'C097' - will correct from the CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **LIKE**. Something like this.

```
SELECT Staff, JobCode FROM tblData WHERE JobCode like '%C097%'
```